# Convert string to class at run time in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have Class Name in Database like "Workcenter" and "Holidays" etc.
and my project namespace is "CMMI.API.Model"
after concate the namespace and table name it become **"CMMI.API.Model.Holidays"** and **"CMMI.API.Model.Workcenter"**
and I want to convert this string class name to application class name. Is Their any way to convert it.
There can be numbers of classes even I don't know the name of classes.

And I don't want to use like this below:

```
object obj;
switch(className)
{
         case "Foo":
        obj = new Foo();
        break;
        case "bar":
        obj = new Bar();
        break;
    ...
}
```

Instead of creating new instance of class in switch statement i want simply convert string to class.

Any help will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
const string objectToInstantiate = "SampleProject.Domain.MyNewTestClass, MyTestProject";
 
var objectType = Type.GetType(objectToInstantiate);

var instantiatedObject = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType) as ITestClass;
```

Still it would be hard to do this if you have different constructors, but with default constructors it will work fine

You also could find another overloads there : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: In the above first line what is namespace and what is class name?

Comment: Before "," is full class name and after - assembly name. You also could provide only full class name

Comment: @SohailShahzad You may be interested also in dependency injection, is is deeply related to this subject

Comment: yes i am interested in dependency injection and i also implemented dependency injection in our solution .

Comment: @bradbury9 from the namespace in the question i think we speak about some DTO objects, not services. No sense in injectiong DTO (and i dont know why should one dynamically create 'em :)))))

Comment: @ bradbury9  Its documentation is very lengthy and i takes time to read documentation before working on the problem.

Comment: @bradbury9 yes  we speak about some DTO objects not service.

Comment: Actually i am creating custom validation from DTO and i did't want to use Data annotation and required attributes on DTO . When i save or update data into database then before saving I validate Model with database fields( database fields keep the information about every fields if it is required or not, regix etc).  When i use PropertyInfo[] properties = type(T).Getprooerties(). From properties i tried to get class name and it return class Name and i con't iterate over string to iterate it must convert into class than iterate it and compare its properties  with database properties.